# Boot Complete broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an app that gives daily notification by alarm manager and it's work well but i have a problem in device reboot i have built the Boot_Complete Broadcast Receiver but i want this broadcast check the service if it was running before reboot or was not running .
and this is my MainActivity.java

```
public void startMorning()
{
    AlarmManager morningAlarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent morningIntent = new Intent(AutoAzkarSetting.this,MorningReciver.class);
    morningIntent.putExtra("numCheck",1);
    moPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AutoAzkarSetting.this, 0, morningIntent, 0);
    Calendar morningCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
    morningCalender.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    morningCalender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    morningAlarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,morningCalender.getTimeInMillis()+12*60*60*1000,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,moPending);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Morning Alarm Set",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and this is MorningReceiver.java

```
public class MorningReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent morIntent = new Intent(context, MorningService.class);
        context.startService(morIntent);
}
}
```

and this is MorningService.java

```
public class MorningService extends Service {

WindowManager windowManager ;
WindowManager.LayoutParams params , params2;
ImageView azkarHead , closeHead;
int morId ;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String morningContent = this.getResources().getString(R.string.notyContent);
        String morningSub = this.getResources().getString(R.string.moevSub);
        Uri MorningSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        final NotificationManager morningManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final Notification morningNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Morning")
                .setContentText(morningContent)
                .setSubText(morningSub)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setSound(MorningSound)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .build();
        morningManager.notify(morId, morningNotification);

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        azkarHead = new ImageView(this);
        azkarHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 150;
        windowManager.addView(azkarHead, params);
        azkarHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent morningIndex = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AzkarList.class);
                morningIndex.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                morningIndex.putExtra("azkarHeadIndex", 0);
                startActivity(morningIndex);
                windowManager.removeView(azkarHead);
                windowManager.removeView(closeHead);
                morningManager.cancel(morId);
            }
        });

        closeHead = new ImageView(this);
        closeHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_clear_white);
        params2 = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params2.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
        params2.x = 10;
        params2.y = 260;
        windowManager.addView(closeHead, params2);
        closeHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                windowManager.removeView(azkarHead);
                windowManager.removeView(closeHead);
                morningManager.cancel(morId);
            }
        });
        startForeground(morId, morningNotification);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

so is there any idea how to do that ?????

Answer (score 0):

You could store if the service was started or stopped in a shared preference, like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("ServiceRunning", true).apply();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("ServiceRunning", false).apply();
}
```

Then you can check in the boot completed receiver if the service was running like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
if (prefs.getBoolean("ServiceRunning", false))
    ...
```

Note that this will work only if you run your application in a single process (the default).

Comment: thanks for your answer , but when the device reboot the service will destroy even if the user was running it and it will save false value and it will not run again